# Converting old python script to work in Blender 2.80

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm trying to convert a python script to work in Blender 2.8
https://github.com/mtyka/attractor/blob/c7edbadcee826ea5d791529cfa329f2c326215ec/attractor.py

I've made the changes to **line 27 to say**  **"blender": (2, 80, 0),**

but I'm getting errors in **line 384** in **addon_utils.py** **which this file doesn't exist on my system (I have 2.79 and 2.80 snap blender Ubuntu 18.04 64bit neither have this file).**

and I'm getting errors in **line 1480** in **attractor.py**

```
def register():
  bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
  bpy.types.INFO_MT_curve_add.append(menu_func)
```

[image: error]

Comment: See also the release notes that explain the changes to the API: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons

Comment: ...and I think `INFO_MT_curve_add` needs to be replaced with `VIEW3D_MT_curve_add`.